# gitolite gitlist: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref

Tags: git, gitolite

I've currently switched to gitolite + gitlist on my private server.
While gitolite works fine, gitlist and also gitweb don't.
While in gitlist i can see the testrepo and my own, gitlist tells me

```
Oops! fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.
```

The config looks valid...

```
[git]
client = '/usr/bin/git' ; Your git executable path
repositories = '/var/www/gitolite/repositories/' ; Path to your repositories

; You can hide repositories from GitList, just copy this for each repository you want to hide
; hidden[] = '/var/www/projects/BetaTest'
hidden[] = /var/www/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin.git

[app]
debug = false

; If you need to specify custom filetypes for certain extensions, do this here
[filetypes]
; extension = type
; dist = xml
```

... and also the repository

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 git git 4096 Sep 23 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 git git 4096 Sep 23 00:19 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 git git   23 Sep 23 00:19 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   2 git git 4096 Sep 23 00:19 branches
-rwxr-xr-x   1 git git   66 Sep 23 00:19 config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 git git  386 Sep 24 17:27 gl-conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 git git 4096 Sep 23 00:19 hooks
drwxr-xr-x   2 git git 4096 Sep 23 00:19 info
drwxr-xr-x 109 git git 4096 Sep 25 00:24 objects
drwxr-xr-x   4 git git 4096 Sep 23 00:19 refs
```

and the HEAD

```
cat HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Any Idea?

Comment: What exact command (git clone, I suppose) is failing? What exact address are you using?

Comment: `HEAD` and `config` shouldn't (usually) be executable. I'd be surprised if this cause a problem, though.

Comment: nope, git clone, push and pull working correctly, (as i said) gitolite works fine. But gitlist shows the repository, but not the content. The error message "Oups!... " shown up.
I've changed the rights for HEAD and Config back to normal, no changes...

Comment: If you have access to the project on your machine, you should try to checkout the hash located in `.git/refs/heads/master` file of your server. This way you'll know if the hash pointer by master on your server is valid or not.

Comment: i tried to check out the master branch on my local machine like
    git@remoteserver:repository -b master
and it worked (hope you mean that, im a novice at git)

Answer (score 0):

Check your tags and branches.

If you have a *tag* named `master`, a [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) of the git repo with the `-b master` option can work too! (`-b` takes a branch name *or* a tag)

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from this problem, too.

In a bare repository "repoName.git" there is probably this file:
`-rw-r--r--   1 git git   23 Sep 19 11:37 HEAD`
with the content:
`ref: refs/heads/master`. Similar postings suggested to check the access rights for this file.

But when I examined the file `repoName.git/refs/heads/master` it had these rights
`-rw------- 1 git git 41 Mar 13 15:22 refs/heads/master`.

Therefore I could solve this problem by changing the rights for this file too (actually I granted a little more, you can try to give less rights):

**`chmod go+r repositories`**

Where 'repositories' is the repositories directory of gitolite.